# globals php help

Tags: php, global

I am trying to use a global in a file that is just used to post data to. The global is not being registered on that page. How can I get the globals accessible in that page.

EDIT maybe I wasnt too clear so let me clear it up. I have these files

index.php

```
global $user;
echo $user->uid;
```

post.php

```
global $user;
echo $user->uid;
```

now from index.php I am posting to post.php through jquery. However when I echo $user->uid from post.php it is not echoing but when I echo it from index.php it is showing it. How can I get that $user->uid accessible from post.php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to access variables from the global scope is to use the special PHP-defined $GLOBALS array.

Example from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

```
<?php
$a = 1;
$b = 2;

function Sum() {
    $GLOBALS['b'] = $GLOBALS['a'] + $GLOBALS['b'];
} 

Sum();
echo $b;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be looking into sessions rather than globals. From what it sounds like, you are registering a variable on one page, then when the user moves to another page, you want that variable to be usable.

Sessions will let you do that. Simply use this code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['my_var'] = 'foo';
```

And on subsequent pages...

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['my_var'];
```

Which will output `foo`.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: This is what you need. Lukman describes the problem, but this is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remember that when the user submits the form and redirect to `post.php`, the variables in `index.php` are long gone. PHP executions are short-lived unlike normal desktop applications.

Whatever you do in `index.php` to get the `$user` object must be repeated in `post.php`. If you don't want to replicate the code, just put it in some file `init_user.php` and have both `index.php` and `post.php` include the file using `include_once('init_user.php');`

Answer (score 0):

if you need a global inside a function do like this

```
function phpFoobarFunction(){
  global $my_global;
}
```

reference about [scoping](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

for [superglobals](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) like `$_POST`, `$_GET` (etc...) they are available **anywhere**.

---

from your updated question, you cannot share variable between two different call of PHP. you would have :

- to recreate your $user class by realoading from the DB (or your source)
- stock the object in the $_SESSION
- pass the user object via javascript(but that's dangerous because user can edit that) and add it has params to your ajax call.

more reference about how PHP play with session [there](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with mattbasta, globals were disabled by security reasons. You can use it anyway but the right way is to use session.

Other thing is, you said: "now from index.php I am posting to post.php through jquery."
Are you using some Ajax call? If not I don't understand why use JS to do this... If you are sending the data through Ajax and only want to send this param try this:

```
<input style="display:none" type="hidden" id="uid" name="uid" value="<?= $user->uid ?>" />
```

And then handle it from your ajax call like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/post.php",
    data: "uid=" + uid + "&otherVar=" + otherVar, //and so on..
    success: function() {
        //Here you can notify the user that the script ran successfully 
        }
});//end of ajax
```

Hope this help you.