# How to assign a post value as a global variable

Tags: php, post, variable-declaration, global

Is there a way in php where you can assign a post value to a variable.

My current code.

```
global $CustomShippingRate;

$CustomShippingRate = empty($_POST['custom-shipping']) ? 0 : floatval($_POST['custom-shipping']);
```

Currently I get an error :

> error: CustomShippingRate uninitialized
>
> error: Exception has occurred. Notice: Undefined variable: CustomShippingRate

Comment: I suggest you to take a look at `$GLOBALS['CustomShippingRate']`, that way you can directly set it and use it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [globals php help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753530/globals-php-help)

Answer (score 0):

please note a post variable is a global itself already but if you want to define a new varialbe based on post data, you can define a variable outside of your local scope and then inside ur scope use global syntax or $GLOBALS[..] and assign a new value to it.